# MySQL Update INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I tried to update a column in a specific table which has a parent table.
The table is `gradings` and the column in this table whose value I want to update is `sy_id.`

The other table `school_years` has column `sy_id` and `sy_dates` which having a value. `2018 -2019, 2019 - 2020....`

I want to update the column `sy_id` in `gradings` but I have no idea how to solve the error.

```
UPDATE gradings
INNER JOIN school_years
ON gradings.sy_id = school_years.sy_dates
INNER JOIN students
ON gradings.student_id = students.id
SET gradings.sy_id = '2017 - 2018'
WHERE students.id = 1;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: WHERE students.id = 1; should be '1' (quoted)?

Comment: @Berniev - No, it is not mandatory to keep 1 quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not joining on the wrong columns, this should work fine:

```
update gradings g,
    school_years sy,
    students s 
set 
    g.sy_id = '2017 - 2018'
where
    g.student_id = s.id
        and g.sy_id = sy.sy_dates
        and s.id = 1
```

Comment: It's the same code i posted above. But the value of the first row in `school_years` table updated to `2017 - 2018`
not updating the column `sy_id` in table `gradings`